# Multiple form constructors in a Form issue

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I have this:

```
public partial class FrmUpload : Form
{
    public FrmUpload()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FrmUpload(Dictionary<string, string> ft) : base()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> ctrl in ft)
        {
            Controls.Find(ctrl.Key, true)[0].Text = ctrl.Value;
        }
    }

    private void BtnCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        Close();
    }

    private void BtnExitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an index exception when I try this. If I debug it I see that InitializeComponent() doesn't run..

Code in my main app:

```
var frmUpload = new FrmUpload(FormTextUpload);
if (frmUpload.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the base class constructor:

```
public FrmUpload(Dictionary<string, string> ft) : base()
```

call your own parameterless contructor:

```
public FrmUpload(Dictionary<string, string> ft) : this()
```

Comment: It worked. I was calling base class (form) constructor instead of my specific forms?